# how to prevent extra stuff being send in req.body in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I was just wondering is it possible to restrict what is been sent in the `req.body`
like can I create a middleware that checks the `req.body` for extra junk before it goes to the controller
is this even an issue?
if I just select the needed data it doesn't matter how bloated is the req.body?

thank you.

Comment: Question makes little sense without some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to reject requests containing body parameters with names that aren't in an allowed list.  It should be relatively easy to do that.

```
const createError = require('http-errors')
const bodyAllowedList = new Set (['username', 'password'])

function checkbody(req,res,next) {
  for (const prop in req.body) {
    if(req.body.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !bodyAllowedList.has(prop)) {
      next(createError(400, 'unexpected parameter in POST body'))
    }
  }
}

route.post('whatever', checkbody, function (req, res, next){
  /* your route handler here. */
})
```

You see the general pattern: look at the properties of the `req.body` object: they are the body parameters. If you see one you don't want call `next(error)` and express will kick an error back to the requestor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some object destructuring as a way to limit the data being passed in and used, but that may clutter up your route handler code. I would go with destructuring in your controller methods, rather than modifying the data through middleware, which can lead to confusion.

For example:

```js
const User = require("./user");
const express = require("express");
const router = new express.Router();

router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => { 
// let's pretend req.body has username, password, and otherJunk.

  //option 1
  const userThing1 = await User.authenticate1(req.body);

  // option 2
  const userThing2 = await User.authenticate2(req.body);

  // option 3
  const { username, password, otherJunk } = req.body;
  const userThing3 = await user.authenticate3({username, password});
 
  // ...do stuff with userThing responses here
}
```

the `User` class with the `authenticate1`, `authenticate2`, `authenticate3` methods are defined below

```js
class User {
  // see route handler first
  static async authenticate1(data) {
    // destructure here, grab only what you need
    const {username, password} = data;
    // do stuff with username and password here. 
    // note that data.otherJunk is still accessible here. 
  }

  static async authenticate2({username, password }) {
   // destructured in the parameters, do stuff with username and password here
   // otherJunk is not accessible here. 
  }

  static async authenticate3({username, password, otherJunk }) {
   // destructured in the parameters, do stuff with username and password here.
  // note that otherJunk will not be accessible because of the way we passed variables into the route handler. 
  }
}

module.exports = User;
```

There are of course many ways to do this, but I'd go with either option 1 or option 2, grabbing `username`, `password`, and ignoring `otherJunk` in the destructuring process. It still allows for the necessary data to be passed through, but makes it so that you're grabbing only what you need for explicitness and readability.